# How to make picasa album API Displays my private Google Photos Albums on my wallpaper App?

Tags: api, picasa

I was working on an android wallpaper app where i use Google picasa album API as where the wallpapers are downloaded from , so i create an album on google photos where i put all the wallpapers images in .
Then i had this problem where albums that i mad on google photos didn't appear on my app , after a little of research i understood that the album should be a public one to appear on the app , then i looked on how to make an google photos album public ? So the answer is that there isn't a way to make an album public any more on google photos albums // there only a limited access mod only but not //
So Now my questions are : 
- is there a way to make a google album public ?
- is there a way can Picasa Album Web Api can read my private or limited access albums ?
- is there an other better way to this same process with an FREE service like googles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Google retired picasa. The api doesnot allow to access album photo anymore. Search for other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you know any alternative ? I can't any...

Comment: Try learning rest framework, django rest framework is great or you can use node js as well to greate api